# Passing more than two values in javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, jsp

In my jsp page I have a javascript function for a button click.In that I need to pass some values to next jsp page.I can able to pass two values as a parameter but while giving three values its not working.Not working means control is not going next page when click on button.

This one works fine

```
window.location.assign("gt_Iba2?value="+uri+"&len="+<%=height%>);
```

This is not working

```
window.location.assign("gt_Iba2?value="+uri+"&len="+<%=height%>+"&SelectedValue="+<%=typeNameToPass%>);
```

**EDIT**

`typeNameToPass` is a string value i'm getting from previous jsp page.

```
String typeNameToPass =request.getParameter("value");
```

My javascript function

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
                function gt2()
                {
                var pqr="100";
                var arr=new Array();
                var x=<%=height%>;
                var attstr=null;
            for(var t=0;t<x;t++)
            {
            var a="inputText"+t;

                var e=document.getElementById(a);
                var val= e.value;
                if(val.indexOf(",") !== -1){
                alert("Legal value Constraint can't allow comma");
                return;
                }
                arr[t]=val;

                if(t==0)
                {
                attstr=arr[t]+",";
                }

                if((t!=x)&&(t!=0))
                {
                if(t==x-1)
                {
                attstr+=arr[t];
                }
                else
                {
                attstr+=arr[t]+",";
                }

                }
          }
            var uri=encodeURIComponent(attstr);
            window.location.assign("gt_Iba2?value="+uri+"&len="+<%=height%>+"&SelectedValue="+<%=typeNameToPass%>);
```

I don't know what's wrong here.Any ideas would be much helpful

Comment: Maybe `<%=typeNameToPass%>` contains quotes?

Comment: What are the values of your `height` and `typeNameToPass`? Maybe they form a wrong js string.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari  No they are string only.Actually height is an integer value

Comment: Please show the actual values which produce an error.

Comment: Can you post the values that `<%=typeNameToPass%>` can take?

Comment: var link = "gt_Iba2?value="+uri+"&len="+<%=height%>+"&SelectedValue="+<%=typeNameToPass%> ;
alert(link);
//your line
and post the answer you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
window.location.assign("gt_Iba2?value="+uri+"&len=<%=height%>&SelectedValue=<%=typeNameToPass%>");
```

Your code works for height, probably because it is number. Then you will get in JS something like `"[...]&len="+80`, but if `typeNameToPass` is a string value you will get `"[...]&len="+80+"&SelectedValue="+someString` - unless `someString` is a variable, you will get error.